# ~ not expanding to home directory in phantomjs script

Tags: bash, phantomjs, launchd

I have two scripts. The first is a basic bash script, called tfile:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger -s "About to try running phantomjs"
logger -s "Current User: "$USER
VAR=$(phantomjs ~/test/phtest.js)
logger -s $VAR
logger -s "Finished running phantomjs"
```

The second is the phantomjs script, phtest.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log("It worked!" + fs.workingDirectory);
fs.write("~/test/testlog.txt","It worked!","w");
phantom.exit();
```

If I run the script tfile from the command line, everything works. It logs the user as me, and phtest outputs the working directory as /Users/myname/test.

Now, I have a launchd file set in ~/Library/LaunchAgents which runs tfile whenever a certain file is changed. When I change that file, the first two lines of tfile run, giving me precisely the same output as before, the phantomjs process is started, but then it hangs. If I kill the process, I get the output:

```
It worked! / Unable to open file '~/test/testlog.txt' :78 in open :135 in write
```

I take this to mean that phantomjs is running at the location /, rather than from my home directory as before.

If I hardcode my home directory instead of using ~ in phtest, then it no longer hangs, but the output from phantomjs is still /.

So my question is: why is the ~ expanded in tfile, regardless of how I run it, but not in phtest? I understand that ~ is a feature of the shell, not the file system, but since in both cases phtest is being called from a bash script, I'm not certain why the expansion is happening in one instance, but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `~` doesn't expand inside double quotes. It's treated as a literal value inside quotes rather than expanding to the home directory.

You can use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

[POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) states:

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the
>   literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the
>   exception of the characters backquote, dollar-sign and backslash.

`~` is in the list of characters that would expand inside double quotes. You can test it easily:

```
$cd ~
$touch test_file
$ls test_file 
test_file
$ls "~/test_file"
ls: cannot access ~/test_file: No such file or directory
$ls ~/test_file
/home/usr/test_file
$
```

Comment: But the ~ is expanded, even inside the double quotes, when I run it from the terminal directly. That is, if I type ./tfile into terminal, then it calls phtest.js, and everything works. It is only when tfile is called by launchd that it fails to expand the ~.

Comment: I am not familiar with launchd. But `~` doesn't get expanded inside quotes no matter whether you call the script directly or through another script.

Comment: Your comment about ~ not expanding in double quotes is helpful, because I didn't know it before, but not for this particular problem, I think. Notice that the ~ in double quotes isn't in a bash script, it's in a phantomjs script. Replacing the ~ with $HOME also fails.

Comment: @aberkow Only shells can expand $HOME or `~` (without quotes) and other languages do not expand/understand it. For example, `fopen("~/file", "r");` would fail (assuming `~/file` exists and readable). I think, it's the same with phantom script. So you have to give full path `/home/user/file`.

Comment: Right, but that's precisely my question. To use your example, `fopen("~/file", "r")` is succeeding in one instance, while failing in the other. The only difference I can detect is whether `tfile` is called from bash directly, or by the daemon. In both cases, `tfile` calls `fopen("~/file","r")`. If `tfile` is called by me from bash, the `fopen` succeeds. If `tfile` is called by the daemon, the `fopen` fails.

Comment: FWIW, I wrote a little phantom script using [this](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html) and I can't reproduce the issue. In fact, it creates a directory `~` in the current directory if I write something to `~/output.txt`. It suggests it clearly doesn't expand `~' and same with `$HOME` too. Perhaps, it creates directory `~` in one instance and seems to "work" in that case for you?

Comment: Excellent! Yes, that is exactly what it was doing. Thanks! And then the reason it is putting the "`~`" directory inside my `~/test` directory when called from bash is because, when called from bash, programs always assume the present working directory. Since I have write access in this directory, in just creates the thing. But this fails in the other case because the working directory when the daemon runs is `/`, and I don't have write access there, so it can't create the `/~`.